# replace and unset $_GET variables

Tags: php

I have buttons in PHP with locations:

```
<input type="button" onClick="parent.location=\'?pagenum='.$back.'\'" value="Previous" />
```

but i would like to be able to keep the rest of the `$_GET` variables in in URL but it will need to remove the current `pagenum` and replace with the new variable

what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: <input type="button" onClick="parent.location=\'?pagenum='<?php echo $back ?>'\'" value="Previous" />

Answer (score 0):

$_GET is an array

if you do `unset($_GET["pagenum"])` you will delete that element, and that's all

Comment: before your <input... 'cos you want to clear your variable before show it

Comment: i have just added this (this one is an ahref link) unset($_GET["status"]);
echo '<a href="?'.$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"].'&status=all"><div class="TicketsMenuTabs""';
if($_GET["status"] == 'all') {
 echo ' id="active"';
}
echo '>Show All Tickets</div></a>'; but in the source code its showing /helpdesk/tickets?id=helpdesk/tickets&id=helpdesk/tickets&id=helpdesk/tickets&status=Customer%20Reply&status=Needs%20Action&status=Open when i click on links

Comment: yeah dude, but you're unsetting $_GET but showing $_SERVER... in that case you must unset $_SERVER and be carefull because you're unsetting $GET["status"] and after are asking by his state...

Comment: unsetting $_SERVER does not work at all. i need to be able to change the current $_GET["status"] value but keep the other $_GET values

Comment: try this. replace your $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] by join("&",$_GET). An also add the unset before your echo '<a (first line)

Comment: unset what? $_GET["status"] ?

Comment: pagenum, that's you asked in the first post

Comment: sorry, im getting mixed up between two different bits of code my end! i have just tried this but for example the code i put it pastebin i done join("&",$_GET); and unset($_GET["status"]); to replace the status variable but its just adding an extra status not amending it

Comment: because i doing the unset before my queries, its not executing the queries because it cannot find the $_GET var

Comment: you're unsetting pagenum and not ussing after... if you still wants to keep $_GET you must clone element... look at this http://pastebin.com/d7gxgDMm

Comment: same again, i have put this code in and its now not running my queries because the variables are being unset

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67132/discussion-between-bredebs-and-user3815283).